# update to java.security file in linux

Tags: java.security

I wanted to update java.security file, jdk.tls.disabledalgorithms java 8 to disable weak ssl/TLS ciphers used by application.I have updated with RSA KeySize <= 1024 to disable algorithms with keysize less than or equal to 1024. but when I run the application, I can see same set of ciphers used. Can someone suggest me how to disable those ciphers.

I wanted to disable RSA ciphers with keystrength less than or equal to 1024

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: We have a parameter in java.security, i.e.,  jdk.tls.disabledalgorithms =RSA KeySize < 1024 , this parameter won't allow application to use RSA ciphers having keysize less tahn 1024 . I run my application using  java. for example: java application.exe
I can see still the application is using old ciphers(i.e., RSA ciphers with keysize less than 1024). Basically i am expecting my application to use RSA ciphers with keysize more then 1024.